# Inserted records not showing in MS Access DB Table

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

Having some issues inserting records from `pyodbc` using `sql` `insert`.
The code runs and it also looks like MS Access table is generating an `ID` but the records are not showing in the table.. No Errors in my application , first time using MS Access and `pyodbc` to insert records. Maybe I need to allow or change setting in Access?

```
import pyodbc 

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;{FIL=MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:\Users\James\Documents;DBQ=C:\Users\James\Documents\Database1.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

def add_new_loancar_to_DB(): 
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute( "INSERT INTO Loan_vehicle_data (Loan_make , Loan_model , Loan_rego) values ('test' , 'test' , 'test')")
```

[image]

Comment: Try conn.commit()

Comment: Kindly place as answer.. That worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you'll need to commit your transaction.

```py
conn.commit()
```